# CFCookie dies on http meta reload

Tags: html, cookies, coldfusion

So I'm writing an experiment program. One of the steps include querying an entry to see if people are ready to move on. I'm more used to PHP, so a "" always did the trick. However, with Coldufusion the following page [posted on Pastebin at the bottom of the page] runs through once, does the meta refresh, and than the cookie dies.

So with flags, I see that the cookie exsited during the first run around, but second and so forth, the cookie dies and brigns the entire experiment to a halt.

So my question is does Coldfusion's cfcookies randomly die after a meta refresh? If so, is there a ColdFusion workaround?

The page with the problem : http://pastebin.com/1BJLahHZ

The page that pulls information from a form and stores it into a cookie : http://pastebin.com/ekP5Ea0U

*The timer on the cookie is two hours [timer = createTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)] so I am pretty sure it's not that.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: We need to see the code where you *write/create* the cookie. The linked code only shows you checking for its existence/reading its values. No enough info.

Comment: The second pastebin shows where the cookie creation is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookie won't ever get set when you use `<cflocation url="http://cbees-dev/newTR3/wait.cfm">`  as this occurs before the page is loaded and rendered to the client, thus the cookie is never set.

Use javascript instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    location.href='http://cbees-dev/newTR3/wait.cfm';
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks again, Dale. :D I guess I'll have to find the JS way of delaying the refresh, too.

Comment: It's prety simple
`setTimeout('http://cbees-dev/newTR3/wait.cfm', 5000);`
The 5000 = 5 seconds.

Comment: Oh yah, forgot to mention, if anyone is going to use this as a reference, the correct javascript is : `<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout("location.href='/url'", 5000)
 </script>`

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a cookie, and then immediately follow it with a cflocation; the http headers necessary to pass the information to your browser to communicate that a cookie is created are flushed away when a cflocation occurs.

Re-design your logic so that your `<CFCOOKIE>` sets are done on pages that have no chance of being redirected away.

Comment: This is probably the better answer, and I should take this logic to heart in the future. D: